# Access symfony parameters within the FeatureContext

Tags: symfony, behat, mink

How can I access symfony parameters (e.g. parameters.yml) within the FeatureContext.php?

If I use `$this->getContainer()->getParameter('currency');` in any controller, I can get the values and I want to do same thing with `FeatureContext` so how can I make code below possible?

Thanks in advance

**I want to make this example work in one way or another:**

```
namespace Football\TeamBundle\Features\Context;

use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext
{
    /**
     * @Then /^I print currency$/
     */
    public function iSeeCurrency()
    {
        echo $this->getContainer()->getParameter('currency');
        sleep(60);
    }
}
```

**Just for reference; this example of mine works fine for accessing symfony services:**

```
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use Behat\Symfony2Extension\Context\KernelDictionary;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext
{
    private $kernel;
    use KernelDictionary;

    public function setKernel($kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }

    /**
     * @Then /^I want to say hello to "([^"]*)"$/
     * @param $seconds
     */
    public function iSayHello($name)
    {
        $container = $this->getContainer();
        $behatService = $container->get('behat_service');

        echo $behatService->sayHello($name);
        sleep(60);
    }
}
```

**CONFIGURATION FILES: (I have _dev.yml and _prod.yml environments as well)**

**config.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: globals.yml }
```

**config_test.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
    - { resource: parameters_test.yml }
```

**parameters_test.yml**

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony_test
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
```

**globals.yml**

```
parameters:
    currency: EUR.USD.GBP
```

Comment: Have you got the same parameters file in every environment ? (prod/dev/test)

Comment: I've updated the post above according to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**FEATURE CONTEXT**

```
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use Behat\Symfony2Extension\Context\KernelDictionary;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext
{
    private $kernel;
    use KernelDictionary;

    public function setKernel($kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }

    /**
     * @Then /^I access only currency parameter$/
     */
    public function printCurrency()
    {
        $container = $this->getContainer();
        echo $container->getParameter('currency');
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice trick.

Tried with success on Behat 3.x.
Just had a `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Runtime Notice: AppBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext and Behat\Symfony2Extension\Context\KernelDictionary define the same property ($kernel) in the composition of AppBundl
  e\Features\Context\FeatureContext. This might be incompatible, to improve maintainability consider using accessor methods in traits instead. Class was composed` error.

So I just removed `private $kernel` from your snippet to solve this error.